# DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: windows-server-2012, ms-access-2013, dsn

I installed `Server 2012 r2` with `access 2013` I get the following error when I try to connect to my data base that was running under `Server 2003` with `access 2000`

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this download http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255 and then try.  If it doesn't work, search "ODBC" then create a new connection for your access database or modify the existing one there.